# Possible to use $(this).parent().parent()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
      <div class="p1">
          <a href="#" class="quickFlipCta"><img src="Test Pictures/QuestionMark.gif" /></a>
      </div>

      <div class="p2">
          <a href="#" class="quickFlipCta"><img src="Test Pictures/flower.gif" /></a>
      </div>
</div>
```

I have a function that is initiated when the user clicks on a link:

```
$('a').click(function(){
   //some code here
});
```

Within the function, I want to access the "wrapper" div. What would be the best way of doing this? I have tried:

```
$('a').click(function(){
     $(this).parent().parent().
     //modification to wrapper
    });
```

But that does not seem to be working.

Comment: Should work. What's it doing instead?

Comment: _What would be the best way of doing this?_ `$('#wrapper')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is perfectly valid, are you sure your click function is being called?

The best way would be to use an id. Just use `$("#wrapper")`

You can also use `.closest` like this `$(this).closest('#wrapper')` although i would recommend the id method over .closest

Check your click function is being called by calling an alert or console.log

```
$('a').click(function(){
   alert("Called");
   console.log("Called");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The function is being called. Maybe there is something wrong with my actual modification: `$(this).parent().parent().css('visibility','hidden').delay(1500).css('visibility','visible');`
The wrapper never disappears, it's always visible.

Comment: Yes, there's something wrong with that, delay only applies to the fx queue. If you want to wait 1500 ms inbetween hiding and showing you'd have to do something like
    `$(this).parent().parent().css('visibility', 'hidden').delay(1500).queue(function(next) {
        $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
        next();
    });`

That looks really messy in a comment, and I may have misremembered exactly how queue works, but it'd be something like that.

Comment: I tried using setTimeout:

`$(this).parent().parent().css('visibility','hidden');
         setTimeout(function(){
          $(this).parent().parent().css('visibility','visible'); }, 1200);`

But now, it only hides and is not visible after the timeout.

Answer (score 2):

While you can use chained parent `$(this).parent().parent()` to traverse up the tree.

It's better to use closest to traverse up looking for the closest parent that matches the selector, thus the only requirement on the markup is that the link is inside `div#wrapper`.

```
  $('a').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('div#wrapper')
   //modification to wrapper
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11476842/1512640) I'll assume you're trying to add a css change to the animation queue. The problem is this can't be done as the `css()` call isn't animating anything so both `css()` calls happen right away.

You can still accomplish what you're trying by doing the following:

```
$('#wrapper').css('visibility','hidden').delay(500).queue(function(next) {
    $('#wrapper').css('visibility','visible');
    next()
});
```

[see jQuery `delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMFZT/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried your method and it just hides the wrapper and does not become visible after the delay.

Comment: Hmm, maybe something else is wrong, I will check for something in the rest of my code. Thanks again, I appreciate it.